# "RegisterPlugin" task was not found in CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

i am trying to deploy the crm project, I am getting following error.

```
 'Error 105 The "RegisterPlugin" task was not found. Check the following: 1.) The name of the task in the project file is the same as the name of the task class. 2.) The task class is "public" and implements the Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask interface. 3.) The task is correctly declared with <UsingTask> in the project file, or in the *.tasks files located in the "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin" directory. <file path\CRM\Microsoft.CrmDeveloperTools.CrmClient.targets    176 4   <path>.CrmPackage'
```

I have tried the solution https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crmbusiness/archive/2014/01/22/crm-2011-error-registering-plugins-and-or-workflows-the-resource-string-errorserializingregfile-for-the-registerplugin-task-cannot-be-found

but no luck. any other clue?

Thank you
JK

Answer (score 0):

That error means you have a MSBuild step to run "RegisterTask" task but that Task wasn't defined in the tasks file (path\CRM\Microsoft.CrmDeveloperTools.CrmClient.targets) (there should be some sort of  which references "RegisterPlugin"), OR, the process can't read from that folder (permissions) or the folder doesn't exists.